# bat file not working in VirtualBox

Tags: batch-file, virtualbox

my bat file

```
@echo off
:loop
tasklist /fi "pid eq 788" | find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2
  goto loop
) else (
  goto continue
)
:continue
del "Run.exe"
ren latest.exe "Run.exe"
start "" "Run.exe" 
start /b " cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

if file is executed on main PC Windows 8.1 its work fine without any error but if i try to run it on VirtualBox Windows XP its not working

got error "no task running with the specified criteria"

any idea why is not working in VM?

Comment: what makes you think, that a task with pid =  788 would have to exist?

Comment: it's really luck that it works on your windows 8 box.

Comment: this code is a part of a bigger AutoIT code that currently i'm trying to implement. https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/163125-updateautoupdate-functions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you aren't running any tasks with the PID of `788`.  A thing to note about PIDs is that they are assigned randomly, with the same program usually having a different PID every time you run it.
IE: the first time you run MyProgram.exe it receives the PID of `1479`, the second time the PID of `1876`, so on and so forth.
**EDIT**: Except for system programs which almost always have a PID under `1000`. And the `System Idle Process` having a PID of `0`, as well as `System Interrupts` having no PID (`-`).